# SocketIO + server + Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, server, socket.io

I'm using SocketIO for the first time with Angular and Node. What I'm doing is sending an API message to the Frontend using SocketIO.

Localhost everything works perfectly. The reception at Angular is as follows:

```
public listen(_envet: string): Observable<any>
{
    const observable = new Observable(observer => 
    {
        socketIO(environment.apiRoot, 
        {
            path: environment.localhost ? null : '/api/'
        }).on(_envet, (data: any) => 
        {
            observer.next(data);
        });
    });

    return observable;
};
```

However when I go up to the server, I get the following message:

```
GET https://www.foverqa.com.br/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NQsBV7h 404 (Not Found)
```

I am not able to solve this problem! I believe it is something related to the route, but I still couldn't solve it!

Can anyone tell me what it can be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem seems to be on the node side?

Comment: @MikeOne For me, it seems to be a problem in the communication of the frontend (angular) with the server. But I still haven't identified what it is.